# Using selection.datum to replace datum? How does it work?

Tags: d3.js

I've got some d3 code that selects and appends an array of 'gateway' objects, as follows:

```
var gwList = chart.selectAll('.gw')
             .data(gateways);

gwList
  .enter()
  .append('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'gw')  // the CSS class to use. Change this!
  .append("svg:path")   // append a path only for each new object, with class 'line'
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .datum(function(d, i) {
      return {object: d, timeValues:null};
  });
```

Notice the .datum() call. I want the entry selection elements to replace their gateway object with an object with 2 properties.

Then I do:

```
gwList
    .selectAll('path.line')
    .data(function(d) {
        // stuff
    });
```

What I can't figure out is, even though I have the 'datum()' call for entry nodes, the value of 'd' in the lower .data() function is always the original gateway object, NOT the modified internal object. The value of 'this' is the selection array of path elements, and they do have a **data** value that is correct. How do I retrieve that, and why isn't it in (d)?

```
d[0].__data__ // gives the right answer
d.data() is an error about object [object Array] has no method 'data'
d[0].data() Object #<SVGPathElement> has no method 'data'
```

I've tried finding an example of selection.datum, but haven't seen one yet that explains this. Can someone please give me a clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of calling 'data()' in the section after selectAll('path.line') I needed to call 'each' or 'call'. That correctly passed the data of the subselection to the function.